# cygwin sshd "getnameinfo failed"

Tags: ssh, cygwin, cygwin-sshd, freesshd

I run an Openssh sshd service from Cygwin. When an RSA connection is established:

```
$ ssh Administrator@ZETA
```

> Last login: Wed May 11 13:58:50 2016 from 10.1.1.140

-- there is no error message.

However, when I use an inline command:

```
$ ssh Administrator@ZETA "echo hi"
```

> hi

-- the command works, but on ZETA the Windows Event Log now says:

> sshd: PID 7068: error: get_socket_address: getnameinfo 2 failed:
>   Unknown error

Calling this often fills the Event Log with errors.

Starting sshd on command line in debug mode:

```
 /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

-- produces no error. It also runs under different user and I had to `chown administrator /var/empty` for it to work.

Trying to start sshd in debug mode as Windows service, as recommended in https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-03/msg00488.html fails:

```
$ /usr/bin/cygrunsrv -I sshd -d "CYGWIN sshd_debug" -p /usr/sbin/sshd -a "-D -d -d -d" -y tcpip
```

> /usr/bin/cygrunsrv: Error installing a service: OpenService:  Win32
>   error 1073: The specified service already exists.

Comment: What is the openssh version? Run `ssh -V` to display the version number.

Comment: @rda OpenSSH_6.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your cygrunsrv error while installing an `sshd_debug` service, you also have to change the `<service_name>` and not only the `<service display name>` in:

```
cygrunsrv -I <service_name> -d "<service display name>" -p <service_path>
```

where

- `<service_name>` is the windows internal service name
- `<service display name>` is the name displayed in `services.msc` list

**OR** you have to stop and remove the already defined service `sshd` first, before trying to define it again using debug parameters.

**Note:** The commands below have to be entered in a shell with **admin privileges**. When sshd is run in **debug mode** with `-d`, `-dd` or `-ddd`, the server will not fork and will only process one connection and then stop.

### To define a second `sshd_debug` service:

To install a second service named `sshd_debug`:

```
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -I sshd_debug -d "CYGWIN sshd_debug" -p /usr/sbin/sshd -a "-D -d -d -d" -y tcpip
```

Note that a particular `<service_name>` or `<service display name>` cannot be defined more than once, otherwise an error will thrown by `cygrunsrv`.

Before you start your new `sshd_debug` service, the normal `sshd` service has to be stopped:

```
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -E sshd
```

Now start the `sshd_debug` service:

```
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -S sshd_debug
```

### To redefine with the existing `sshd` service_name:

Another example which will make the `cygrunsrv` command from your question work (using the service name: `sshd`):

```
# Stop the service
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -E sshd

# Remove the service
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -R sshd

# Install using the same service_name with debug options
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -I sshd -d "CYGWIN sshd_debug" -p /usr/sbin/sshd -a "-D -d -d -d" -y tcpip

# Start the service
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -S sshd
```

### To install a service under a specific account

```
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv -I sshd_debug -d "CYGWIN sshd_debug" -p /usr/sbin/sshd -a "-D -d -d -d" -y tcpip -u "<account_name>" -w "<password>"
```

### Error: `get_socket_address: getnameinfo 2 failed`

The function `get_socket_address` throwing the error message is defined in `canohost.c`:

```
static char *
get_socket_address(int sock, int remote, int flags)
{
    ...
    switch (addr.ss_family) {
    case AF_INET:
    case AF_INET6:
        /* Get the address in ascii. */
        if ((r = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrlen, ntop,
            sizeof(ntop), NULL, 0, flags)) != 0) {
            error("get_socket_address: getnameinfo %d failed: %s",
                flags, ssh_gai_strerror(r));
            return NULL;
        }
        return xstrdup(ntop);
    ...
    }
}
```

It calls a function `getnameinfo` with flag `NI_NUMERICHOST`, which should return a string with the human readable IP address of either the (remote) peer_ipaddr or the local_ipaddr. However, the function fails with an unknown `EAI_SYSTEM` error (`A system error occurred`).

So this does not help a lot, but it might indicate that the error has to do with DNS name resolution.

To troubleshoot you could check if the name resolution is working:

```
# netstat: check where sshd listens and if you have any errors
netstat -ano | grep ":22"
netstat -ao | grep ":22"


# reverse dns lookup
nslookup <remote_ip_address>
nslookup <local_ip_address>

# forward dns lookup (using the hostnames returned by the above commands)
nslookup <remote_hostname>
nslookup <local_hostname>


# or for example using dig

# reverse dns lookup
dig -x <remote_ip_address>
dig -x <local_ip_address>

# forward dns lookup (using the hostnames returned by the above commands)
dig <remote_hostname> +search
dig <local_hostname> +search
```

- The `reverse dns lookup` should return the **fqdn**
- The `forward dns lookup` should return the **IP address**

Comment: Thank you. This does not work for me, however. Both second service and redefining existing service succeed, but cannot start:```$ /usr/bin/cygrunsrv -S sshd_debug1
/usr/bin/cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: QueryServiceStatus:  Win32 error 1062:
The service has not been started.
```. Normal sshd service always starts.

Comment: Also after "Install using the same service_name with debug options" I don't know how to restore what was installed before.

Comment: On my system I had the same, it could be a bug or something else not working. I had to define the service twice using `cygrunsrv -I` (on the second attempt I had an error: `service already exists...`) but after that the start command `cygrunsrv -S` worked. Also check `netstat -ano` and the task manager (all processes) if the `sshd` process is still running, I had to kill it manually sometimes.

Comment: To restore the original configuration, stop any running sshd service `cygrunsrv -E <service>`, remove the sshd services `cygrunsrv -R sshd` (and optional `cygrunsrv -R sshd_debug`). Then from  a privileged shell run `/usr/bin/ssh-host-config`. You can also check what the script does exactly, by running `cat /usr/bin/ssh-host-config | grep -B 2 -A 10 "cygrunsrv -I"`

Comment: Service restored by ssh-host-config. I will try to run debug as a separate service. So far no luck though.

Comment: Partial success. I went to Windows Services and found that the original sshd was using account/password. Modified sshd_debug service with the same and it started.

Comment: This is the -d -d -d debug info I get on the client side now: ```...debug3: Copy environment: WINDIR=C:\\Windows
get_socket_address: getnameinfo 2 failed: Unknown error
``` not as helpful as I had expected